# Creating a Custom Estimator: State Mean Estimator

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've trying to develop a very simple initial model to predict the amount of fines a nursing home might expect to pay based on its location.

**This is my class definition**

```
#initial model to predict the amount of fines a nursing home might expect to pay based on its location
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin, TransformerMixin

class GroupMeanEstimator(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    #defines what a group is by using grouper
    #initialises an empty dictionary for group averages
    def __init__(self, grouper):
        self.grouper = grouper
        self.group_averages = {}

    #Any calculation I require for my predict method goes here
    #Specifically, I want to groupby the group grouper is set by
    #I want to then find out what is the mean penalty by each group
    #X is the data containing the groups
    #Y is fine_totals
    #map each state to its mean fine_tot
    def fit(self, X, y):
        #Use self.group_averages to store the average penalty by group
        Xy = X.join(y) #Joining X&y together
        state_mean_series = Xy.groupby(self.grouper)[y.name].mean() #Creating a series of state:mean penalties
        #populating a dictionary with state:mean key:value pairs
        for row in state_mean_series.iteritems():
            self.group_averages[row[0]] = row[1]
        return self

    #The amount of fine an observation is likely to receive is based on his group mean
    #Want to first populate the list with the number of observations
    #For each observation in the list, what is his group and then set the likely fine to his group mean.
    #Return the list
    def predict(self, X):
        dictionary = self.group_averages
        group = self.grouper
        list_of_predictions = [] #initialising a list to store our return values
        for row in X.itertuples(): #iterating through each row in X
            prediction = dictionary[row.STATE] #Getting the value from group_averages dict using key row.group
            list_of_predictions.append(prediction)
        return list_of_predictions
```

**It works for this**
`state_model.predict(data.sample(5))`

**But breaks down when I try to do this:**
`state_model.predict(pd.DataFrame([{'STATE': 'AS'}]))`

My model can't handle the possibility, and I would like to seek help in rectifying it.

Comment: there might be a couple of problems here, you might have the indexing wrong on `group_averages`, you don't have the `AS` state defined in the `group_averages`, what does `row[0]` look like in your fit function

Comment: How do I define the ```AS``` state in ```group_averages```?

Specifically, I'm honestly not too sure what  

```state_model.predict(pd.DataFrame([{'STATE': 'AS'}]))``` is trying to do.

Row[0] in fit is the name of the state.

Comment: perhaps if you could show me the content of  `self.group_averages`, I might be able to help.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/dNiqrY.jpg

The group_averages will contain a dictionary mapping each state to its sum.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting? if you do this 
`state_model.predict(pd.DataFrame([{'STATE': 'AS'}]))`

Comment: Hi, I am getting a key error (https://snipboard.io/cU8gKR.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I am seeing is in your `fit` method, [`iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) basically iterates over columns rather than rows. you should use `itertuples` which will give you row wise data. just change the loop in your `fit` method to

```
for row in pd.DataFrame(state_mean_series).itertuples(): #row format is [STATE, mean_value]
    self.group_averages[row[0]] = row[1]
```

and then in your predict method, just do a fail safe check by doing

```
prediction = dictionary.get(row.STATE, None) # None is the default value here in case the 'AS' doesn't exist. you may replace it with what ever you want
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your method, instead ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'itertuples'``` is produced at the Pipeline step.

Added a link to the Jupyter file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NHf7DenPGvhXbMbW7MwadZoVDwH1jLTO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dumbchimp I went through your file, and I have updated the answer.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! You were great help! It wasn't just returning none, but the fact that the grader fed a list of dictionaries as well!

Comment: Help, I got an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'itertuples'` is produced when submitting to grader

Comment: @JansenSimanullang do you have this line `pd.DataFrame(state_mean_series).itertuples()` in the for loop?

Comment: The problem solved with conversion of  X to DataFrame by prepending the line `if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame): X = pd.DataFrame(X);` in the `predict` method.