# Difference between ML function calls

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What is the difference between this (did not get it to work)

```
state_model.predict(pd.DataFrame([{'STATE': 'AS'}]))
```

and this (which i got to work)?

```
state_model.predict(data.sample(5))
```

Specifically, I don't understand what is going on for this:

```
state_model.predict(pd.DataFrame([{'STATE': 'AS'}]))
```

I gave my class definition in a different thread:
[Creating a Custom Estimator: State Mean Estimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264671/creating-a-custom-estimator-state-mean-estimator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the predict method was being fed a state that didn't exist, hence I just needed to get my model to respond to missing data in the X matrix.

'''python
state_model.predict(pd.DataFrame([{'STATE': 'AS'}]))
'''